# Copying half the field separated by comma

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, joomla3.0

I have google map giving me coordinate values into one field, but I would need to keep this field and have it somehow coppied to another 2 fields

```
<input class="coordinates">50.48820,13.64855</input>
<input class="longtitude"></input>
<input class="latitude"></input>
```

as far as my tries went I made this

```
var s1=document.getElementById('coordinate');
var s2=document.getElementById('longtitude');
s1.onchange=function(){
s2.value=s1.value;
}
```

but I didnt come up with any way to implement the separation by comma

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<input id="coordinates" value="50.48820,13.64855"></input>
<input id="longtitude"></input>
<input id="latitude"></input>

var s1=document.getElementById('coordinates');
var s2=document.getElementById('longtitude');
var s3=document.getElementById('latitude');
s1.onchange=function(){
  s2.value=s1.value.split(",")[0];
  s3.value=s1.value.split(",")[1];
}
```

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uzso33av/

Comment: I'm glad to see that some people still use vanilla JS instead of JQuery for doing simple tasks like this. +1 for the sake of lightness.

Comment: Works, ty very much sir.

Answer (score 0):

Use `split` function.

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp

```js
$('.coordinates').change(function(){
  var a = $(this).val().split(',');  
  $('.longtitude').val(a[0]);
  $('.latitude').val(a[1]);
}).trigger('change');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="coordinates" value="50.48820,13.64855" />
<input class="longtitude" />
<input class="latitude" />
```